# Add a new partition to existing topic and assign it to a specific node

Tags: apache-kafka

There was a topic with 6 partitions and that time we were using a cluster with 3 nodes. Then we added a 4th node. In Kafka you can increase the number of partitions for an existing topic with the `./kafka-topics --alter --topic my_topic --partitions 8` cli command. While doing that, I was expecting Kafka to assign the 2 new partitions to 4th node (or at least 1 partition). But It went with the "start from the beginning" method I guess, because both 7th and 8th partitions are declared for first and second node, respectively.

Is there a way that allows me to tell Kafka to assign which partition to which node? If not, why Kafka didn't use an empty node (for that topic) and went with the same nodes?

Comment: It's not "start from beginning". If you run `kafka-topics --describe`, and look at the broker IDs, then partitions can only be assigned to those servers, so you need to manually edit that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not a one-time operation I suggest you to use tool like CruiseControl, that can enforce equal distribution of partition between brokers.
If not, you can use `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh`

topics-to-move.json:

```
{
  "topics": [
    {"topic": "my_topic"}
  ],
  "version":1
}
```

and then run:

```
##it will output the json with new mappings, copy it to t1.json
./kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --topics-to-move-json-file topics-to-move.json --broker-list "0,1,2,3" --generate
## starts moving
./kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --reassignment-json-file t1.json --execute
## verifies, can run all the time to monitor progress
./kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --reassignment-json-file t1.json --verify
```

also, big suggestion to have Replication factor of 2 or greater.

Comment: Note: `--zookeeper` flag is deprecated

Comment: @OneCricketeer , yes in newer versions it is deprecated. Author didn't specify which version he is using ;)

Comment: do I need to give all brokers in --broker-list "0,1,2,3" part? Is it gonna distribute all partitions between these brokers?

Comment: @BünyaminŞentürk well, you need to provide a list of broker on which you want to distribute the topic-partitions.